# How to determine if a contract with a create2 address exists?

Tags: solidity, create2

Say I have a factory contract that creates child contracts using `create2` where a child contract may have never existed or may have existed but no longer exists by for example self-destructing, how can I check(inside the contract's `createChild` method) if the contract with **create2 address** `x` exists presently so as to not attempt to re-instantiate it or should I instead allow it to attempt to re-instantiate and have the call revert as you can't instantiate an already existent contract.

Comment: I have never tried this so I don't know for sure if it would work, but perhaps you could try using a try/catch block to call a function on the contract. I would guess that if the contract has not been deployed or has self-destructed, the catch block would be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple test example in Remix which demonstrates:

1. a create2 contract that presently exists cannot be re-instantiated
2. a create2 contract that becomes non-existent after being created
   can be re-instantiated normally as it was initially instantiated.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Factory {

    mapping(uint => address) children;

    function createChild(uint id) public returns(address child) {

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(id));
        child = address(new Child{salt: salt}(id));

        children[id] = child;

    }

    function destruct(uint childId) public {

        address _child = children[childId];

        Child child = Child(_child);

        child.selfDestruct();
    }
}

contract Child {

    uint immutable public id;

    constructor(uint _id) {
        id = _id;
    }

    function selfDestruct() public {

        selfdestruct(payable(address(this)));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getAddress` function below to view a child's address without attempting a deployment.
When you have `address child` you can use `child.code.length` to get the runtime-bytecode length of the contract at that address: if it's different from zero, it means there's already a deployed contract there.

```
contract Factory {
    ...

    function createChild(uint256 id) public returns(address child) {
        child = getAddress(id);
        if (child.code.length != 0) return child; // do nothing, already deployed

        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(id));
        new Child{salt: salt}(id);

        children[id] = child;
    }
  
    function getAddress(uint256 id) public view returns(address) {
        bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(id));
        bytes32 bytecodeHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(Child).creationCode, id));

        bytes32 _data = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bytes1(0xff), address(this), salt, bytecodeHash));
        return address(uint160(uint256(_data)));
    }
}

contract Child {
    ...

    constructor(uint256 _id) {
        id = _id;
    }
}
```